# How to make a custom keyboard using Objective-C that can type images

Tags: objective-c, uiinputviewcontroller

I want to make a custom keyboard that types custom emojis instead of just letters and numbers. 
The following code helps me type just a letter or number

> `[self.textDocumentProxy insertText:[key currentTitle]];`

but if I change "currentTitle" to "currentImage" it does not result in the correct action because "insertText" is not expecting an UIImage. Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Emojis are characters that are represented by images.

`[self.textDocumentProxy insertText:""];`

If you know the code of the emoji:

`[self.textDocumentProxy insertText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", 0xe04e]];`

Comment: Hi! I want to add custom emojis, like ones I drew. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You can't pass an image through `textDocumentProxy`, which is designed for text. I would try to create a custom subclass of UIInputView, assign it to `inputView` and handle the images through dedicated closures that are designed to pass image types.