# How to create custom keyboard that types custom images?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, image, keyboard

I want to create a custom image keyboard. A keyboard that an user can use and type images that I personalized. So essentially it would be similar to the emoji keyboard, but with emojis I created. I have done so much research about this but have not found clear directions on this topic. I am using Xcode and the language objective-C. I have created a keyboard, but it only types symbols, letters, numbers, or images that already exist and I do not know how to make it type an image of my choice. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add Stickers in Custom KeyBoard Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31741015/add-stickers-in-custom-keyboard-extension)

Comment: While the paste workaround comes from over 4 years ago, [Bitmoji FAQ](https://support.bitmoji.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001476283-Send-Bitmoji-Stickers-) updated this month still mention the paste workaround, so it doesn't seem there's any simple type to paste on iOS anytime soon

Comment: See [How to make a custom keyboard using Objective-C that can type images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61990570/how-to-make-a-custom-keyboard-using-objective-c-that-can-type-images)